# Why won't my site display content images?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My website won't display images on http://teretana.mk/. When I open the debugging console in Chrome I get 2 errors which I do not understand at all.

[image]

It's also really weird if you go in a post like this one http://teretana.mk/2016/04/22/td_d_slug_20/ you can actually drag the blank image in Chrome (maybe in other browsers too) and the actual image will display.

Comment: Make sure the url to your image is correct. Also the jQuery selector is invalid, should be `a[href*='#']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In style.css your `body.lazy-animation .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.lazy-animation .post img` rule has `opacitiy: 0` which is hiding all the images. If you remove that then they show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it in the Chrome developer tools, and it works, I also see defined transition in the class, I'm guessing it was meant to go from transparent to fully visible, but something is broken. I'll just remove the opacity altogether now.